# Xamarin.Android Material Design Icons

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, material-design

## A bit of context:

I was looking into the Material Design Support Library for Xamarin and found [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/add-beautiful-material-design-with-the-android-support-design-library/) article about various controls from this library.

I tried to reproduce the `Toolbar` from the last example (for now I'm not even thinking about implementing the whole hamburger navigation example, just the toolbar with the button). I set it up, created `MyTheme` with my colors, added the fixes for `style-v21` and so on. Everything works well so far, though the `<include ... />` node throws a warning that it's not a recognized child for `RelativeLayout`. Still, it's building correctly so I can deal with it for the most part.

## The problem:

Here's where my problem starts:

```
...
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.main_layout);
    var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar (toolbar);

    //Enable support action bar to display hamburger
    SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator (Resource.Drawable.ic_menu);
    SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);
...
```

With the `SupportActionBar` set up like that, it doesn't display the button. Also, the `ic_menu` drawable seems to be missing. In fact, there aren't any that start with `ic_`, only `abc_`.

Am I missing something here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://material.io/icons/ and download menu icon and then add that icon to the drawable folder and then replace ic_menu in your code with the image name.

NOTE: Do not add image extension name like .jpg,.png with image name

Comment: Oh, so it's not referencing a system-defined drawable! I see, I see. Thanks, I was under the impression that there's a way to reference a system version/theme-specific drawable for a menu :D